# How do you connect to unencrypted server session using GoLang SSH

Tags: go, encryption, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a unencrypted Server that uses "none" for the cipher, `keyExchange` and `HostKeyAlgorithm`. I have tried to do this with the base SSH package in go but when I send the request the "none" value for ciphers is set to nil since it is not an approve cipher.

I am using the code below to set up the client config that will be sent to the sever. The "none" value is accepted for `HostKeyCallback` and `HostKeyAlgorithm` but not for Ciphers because the cipher value must be in the list of approved ciphers. In theory, the cipher shouldn't matter as it should only be used when using encryption.

```golang
clientConfig := ssh.ClientConfig{
        User:            "user",
        Timeout:         10 * time.Second,
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
        Config: ssh.Config{
            KeyExchanges: []string{"none"},
            Ciphers:      []string{"none"},
        },
        HostKeyAlgorithms: []string{"none"},
    }

    sshClientConn, chans, reqs, err := ssh.NewClientConn(s.socket, "", &clientConfig)
```

This gives the error

```
 failed to create ssh session: error creating ssh client connection: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: no common algorithm for client to server cipher; client offered: [], server offered: [none]
```

Answer (score 1):

The SSH protocol is designed to provide a secure, encrypted connection.  That's in the name: Secure Shell.  The protocol as specified in the RFCs does not anticipate negotiating an unencrypted connection since that's specifically contrary to the purpose of the protocol.  If people wanted an unencrypted connection that could be easily tampered with, they would have stuck with telnet.

However, there are some patches floating around that allow specially patched versions of OpenSSH to accept `none` on the idea that encryption is too expensive (which, these days, is almost never the case).  The `none` algorithms are not widely supported because they are insecure, and I don't believe that the Go SSH library supports them.  If you're using a standard library or implementation on the server side, the Go SSH library can probably interoperate with it using one of the normal ciphers provided you use a version from the last week or so (when it was patched to implement RSA with SHA-2).  Otherwise, if the server only supports the `none` cipher, you'll need to use an alternate approach.